# Calendar asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a calendar control to use in a scheduling system. I've searched for one but could only find this bad one http://www.daypilot.org/try.html

I am just wondering can I use the standard ASP.NET calendar, change it's size and use it like the Outlook calendar?

Comment: use some css designs on asp calendars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this controllers one of them Javascript & other asp.net can work with asp.net web Form or MVC

```
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
http://scheduler-net.com/index.html
http://www.daypilot.org/compare-versions.html
```